# Split date column into two

Tags: python, pandas, date, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

| date | wind (°) | wind (kt) | temp (C°) | humidity(%) | currents (°) | currents (kt) | stemp (C°) | sea_temp_diff | wind_distance_diff | wind_speed_diff | temp_diff | humidity_diff | current_distance_diff | current_speed_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 12018 | 175.000000 | 16.333333 | 25.500000 | 82.500000 | 60.000000 | 0.100000 | 25.400000 | -1.066667 | 23.333333 | -0.500000 | -0.333333 | -12.000000 | 160.000000 | 6.666667e-02 |
| 9 12019 | 180.000000 | 17.000000 | 23.344828 | 79.724138 | 230.000000 | 0.100000 | 23.827586 | -0.379310 | 22.068966 | 1.068966 | 0.827586 | -7.275862 | 315.172414 | 3.449034e+02 |
| 10 12020 | 365.000000 | 208.653846 | 24.192308 | 79.346154 | 355.769231 | 192.500000 | 24.730769 | 574.653846 | 1121.923077 | 1151.153846 | 1149.346154 | -19.538462 | 1500.000000 | 1.538454e+03 |
| 14 22019 | 530.357143 | 372.964286 | 23.964286 | 81.964286 | 1270.714286 | 1071.560714 | 735.642857 | -533.642857 | -327.500000 | -356.892857 | 1.857143 | -10.321429 | -873.571429 | -8.928107e+02 |
| 15 22020 | 216.551724 | 12.689655 | 24.517241 | 81.137931 | 288.275862 | 172.565517 | 196.827586 | -171.379310 | -8.965517 | 3.724138 | 1.413793 | -7.137931 | -105.517241 | -1.722724e+02 |
| 16 32019 | 323.225806 | 174.709677 | 25.225806 | 80.741935 | 260.000000 | 161.451613 | 25.709677 | 480.709677 | 486.451613 | 483.967742 | 0.387097 | 153.193548 | 1044.516129 | 9.677065e+02 |
| 17 32020 | 351.333333 | 178.566667 | 25.533333 | 78.800000 | 427.666667 | 166.666667 | 26.600000 | 165.533333 | -141.000000 | -165.766667 | 166.633333 | 158.933333 | 8.333333 | 1.500000e-01 |
| 18 42017 | 180.000000 | 14.000000 | 27.000000 | 5000.000000 | 200.000000 | 0.400000 | 25.400000 | 2.600000 | 20.000000 | -4.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | -90.000000 | -1.000000e-01 |
| 19 42019 | 694.230769 | 589.769231 | 24.038462 | 69.461538 | 681.153846 | 577.046154 | 26.884615 | -1.346154 | 37.307692 | -1.692308 | 1.500000 | 4.769231 | 98.846154 | 1.538462e-01 |
| 20 42020 | 306.666667 | 180.066667 | 24.733333 | 75.166667 | 427.666667 | 166.666667 | 26.800000 | 165.066667 | 205.333333 | 165.200000 | 1.100000 | -4.066667 | 360.333333 | 3.334233e+02 |
| 21 52017 | 146.333333 | 11.966667 | 22.900000 | 5000.000000 | 116.333333 | 0.410000 | 26.066667 | -1.553333 | 8.666667 | 0.833333 | -0.766667 | 0.000000 | 95.000000 | -1.300000e-01 |
| 22 52019 | 107.741935 | 12.322581 | 23.419355 | 63.032258 | 129.354839 | 0.332258 | 25.935484 | -1.774194 | 14.838710 | 0.096774 | -0.612903 | -14.451613 | 130.967742 |  |

I need to sort the 'date' column chronologically, and I'm wondering if there's a way for me to split it two ways, with the '10' in one column and 2017 in another, sort both of them in ascending order, and then bring them back together.

I had tried this:

```
australia_overview[['month','year']] = australia_overview['date'].str.split("2",expand=True)
```

But I am getting error like this:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please fix your data snippet and provide an [mcve] to show what you tried so far and where you are stuck at the moment.

Comment: australia_overview[['month','year']] = australia_overview['date'].str.split("2",expand=True)
australia_overview

Trying this code, but get a ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
...                    'date': ['1 42018', '12 32019', '8 112020', '23 42021']}, 
...                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3]) 
>>> df
   id   date
0   1   1 42018
1   2   12 32019
2   3   8 112020
3   4   23 42021
```

We can `split` the column to get the first value of day like so :

```py
>>> df['day'] = df['date'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[0]
>>> df
    id  date        day
0   1   1 42018     1
1   2   12 32019    12
2   3   8 112020    8
3   4   23 42021    23
```

And get the 4 last digit from the column `date` for the year to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['year'] = df['date'].str[-4:].astype(int)
>>> df
    id  date        day year
0   1   1 42018     1   2018
1   2   12 32019    12  2019
2   3   8 112020    8   2020
3   4   23 42021    23  2021
```

Bonus : as asked in the comment, you can even get the month using the same principle :

```py
>>> df['month'] = df['date'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[1].str[:-4].astype(int)
>>> df
    id  date        day year    month
0   1   1 42018     1   2018    4
1   2   12 32019    12  2019    3
2   3   8 112020    8   2020    11
3   4   23 42021    23  2021    4
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please validate this answer as it solved your problem ?

Comment: The answer has been updated to also get the month, working for one or two digit as requested.